# since he became manager

Tags: tense, since

a. He is growing since he became manager.

b. He is growing since he has become manager.

Are both sentences grammatically correct?

Does 'since' have a temporal meaning in both or could it mean 'because'?

Is there any difference in their meanings?

Answer (score 3):

Neither of them rings true to me. I would choose between

> He has been growing since he became a manager

to emphasise that it has been happening over a long period

> He has grown since he became a manager

when I just want to state that it happened without specifying exactly how or when during the period since his promotion to manager. Note that we need the indefinite article before  manager here. If it was a specific title we could omit it.

> He has grown since he became Chief Executive
> Jürgen Klopp has grown since he became manager of Liverpool FC

Comment: The null article with "manager" sounds fine. "I have done a lot since I became manager". "Manager" is a title and it is very common that it goes with the null article.

Comment: @EddieKal that may be a dialectal difference between us but I have added another example to try to differentiate between manager in general and specific manager.

Answer (score -1):

I agree 100% with mdewey's answer (and EddieKal's comment supporting the null article).

For completeness, yes "since" has the temporal meaning in both sentences.

Comment: What if nobody reads Eddie Kayle's comment?  Good answers have to be self contained, visitors shouldn't be asked to search through comments, even when that number is low.

Comment: "For completeness" could do wih a little more fleshing out by explaining why "since ="because" dies not make sense.